# Use function within generate_series

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I'm new using postgres and the PL/pgSQL. My code is below . I want to modify my code to compare value of variable with the generate series function like:

```
if variable == '2019-08-22' then 
generate_series(date_trunc('day', s.beg), date_trunc('day', 
least(s.enddate, current_date)), interval '1 day') gs(date)
else 
generate_series(date_trunc('day', s.beg), date_trunc('day', 
least(s.enddate, $$var$$)), interval '1 day') gs(date)
```

Below my code.
Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO $$||table_name||$$
(number_, date, type, minutes)
 select
     number_, gs.date,
      (case
            when trim(string) ~ '^XYZ[0-9]$'
       then 'ALPHANUMERIC'
      end) as type,
sum(extract(epoch from (least(s.enddate, gs.date + interval '1 day' -
                           greatest(s.beg, gs.date)
                          )
              ) / 60) as minutes
from table s cross join lateral
generate_series(date_trunc('day', s.beg), date_trunc('day', 
least(s.enddate, current_date)), interval '1 day') gs(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be a `CASE` expression:

```
generate_series(
   date_trunc('day', s.beg),
   date_trunc(
      'day',
      least(
         s.enddate,
         CASE WHEN var = '2019-08-22'
              THEN current_date
              ELSE var
         END
      )
   ),
   interval '1 day'
)
```

Never construct an SQL statement with string concatenation, it makes you vulnerable to SQL injection. Use `format`:

```
format('INSERT INTO %I VALUES ...', table_name)
```

Comment: thank you but i have error saying mismatched parentheses at or near ")"      END)

Comment: I tested it and counted the parentheses. My code fragment seems to be fine.

Comment: My god what should i do :/ . I wrote the samething !! generate_series(date_trunc('day', s.beg), date_trunc('day',
least(s.enddate,
CASE WHEN $$var$$ = '2019-08-22'
              THEN current_date
              ELSE $$var$$
         END
)), interval '1 day') gs(date)

Comment: and im still having the error :/ i have error saying mismatched parentheses at or near ")" END)

Comment: I told you, don't use string concatenation. Your code will become more readable, and it will become safe.